# Solidity - Simple API request - Undeclared identifier problem

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am new in Solidity and currently, I am trying to deploy a simple smart contract that requests ETH price **"LOWDAY"**, and "HIGHDAY". I already did a very similar SC that requests only "VOLUME24HOUR" and it worked great. This is the error that I get:

> contracts/API_Consumer_Info.sol:24:66: DeclarationError: Undeclared
> identifier. Did you mean "jobID"? Chainlink.Request memory request =
> buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

^---^

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumerInfo is ChainlinkClient
{
uint256 public lowDay;
uint256 public highDay;

address private oracle;
bytes32 private jobID;
uint256 private fee;

constructor() public
{
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
    oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
    jobID = "29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8";
    fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18;
}

function requestLowDay() public returns (bytes32 requestID)
{
    Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);  //Error occur here
    request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.LOWDAY");
    int timesAmount = 10**2;
    request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
}

function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _dayLow) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
{
    lowDay = _dayLow;
}

function requestHighDay() public returns (bytes32 requestID)
{
    Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);  //Error occur here
    request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.HIGHDAY");
    int timesAmount = 10**2;
    request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
}

function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _dayHigh) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
{
    highDay = _dayHigh;
}

function withdrawLink() external 
{
    LinkTokenInterface linkToken = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    require(linkToken.transfer(msg.sender, linkToken.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
}
}
```

The base code is not written by my and it works perfectly with "VOLUME24HOUR" call. When I did the necessary changes to request.add("path") and added new variable lowDay/highDay it started to throw error.

Thank you ʕっ•ᴥ•ʔっ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity variable names are case-sensitive.

You have defined a `bytes32` property named `jobID` (uppercase `D`) but then you're trying to pass `jobId` (lowercase `d`).

**Solution:** Pass the correct case-sensitive variable name. In your case `jobID`.